# Keyboard move up and down

Tags: ios, view, keyboard, uitextfield, swift3

I have a loginView, inside that i have two textFields and a button. I have to move up the view while tapping on textField and move down the view when press the return key.

My problem is that it is working fine for all conditions but while tap on the one textField view is moving up but at same time when we go for next textField view is moving down.

```
import UIKit
class CheckFontIconView: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    var activeField: UITextField?

    @IBOutlet weak var loginFieldsView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mobileNo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mobileNo.delegate = self
        textFieldPassword.delegate = self

        registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    @IBAction func btnLoginAction(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    deinit {

        //NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        self.deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    }


    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {

        //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications() {

        //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {

        //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        if self.activeField != nil {
            self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize?.height)!
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {

        //Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize?.height)!
        self.loginFieldsView.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.activeField = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.activeField = nil

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        activeField?.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest way is you make a flag to mark your keyboard was shown or not. So handling it in case not shown or case move to the next textField.

Comment: Yes I tried the same that set the flag earlier but same problem was coming.

Comment: If you will use UIScrollView in your login view then may be you issue will fix.

Comment: I tried running your code and got problem when i select the first textfield, while keyboard was shown i continue to select the second textfield and your view moved up one more time. So i think you should change your calculation method.

Comment: In my opinion, you should store original view frame value and movedUp view frame for switching it, not using             `self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize?.height)!`

Comment: Yes @nynohu problem is that only.
How can I fix it.
Is there any alternative?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once try with scrollView,I hope it will help you.

Use a scroll view to moving text field up and down.

**Making Up**

1. Make a @IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!;
2. Under textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField method
3. Create a CGPoint with x: 0 and y texfield.frame.origin.y
4. And then start moving the scroller with setContentOffset:animated function.(Parameter will be your CGPoint and a boolean value true).

**Making Down**

1. Under textFieldDidEndEditing:textField set your scroller to CGPoint.zero with  same setContentOffset:animated function.

*And your textFieldShouldReturn:textField should be resignFirstResponder or to next textField.

Please let me know if having any problem on this.

Comment: But I have only two textFields, why should I use scrollView.
Thanks

Comment: Your concern correct but anyhow, you want to move the view right?If you use scrollView it will help you to Scroll up and down according to your keyboard movement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for ask question...

Use [TPKeyboard](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) to achieve above functionality then no manage this kind of stuff (Automatically manage by TPKeyboard)...

**Update:**

I think you have done some mistake in given below code...

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.activeField = nil
 }
```

You have to DEBUG and identify exact issue..

Happy coding...

Comment: I don't want to use any Library.

Comment: I DEBUG but not getting problem.

Comment: Yeah sure How can I

Comment: Please upload your project in google drive or GitHub and share download link

Comment: I don't know the steps to upload project on GitHub.
I tried but have to learn.
Please give me your mail ID , I will  send zip file.Thanks'

Comment: hiteshsurani314@gmail.com

Comment: OK Please check your mail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127776/discussion-between-hitesh-surani-and-kishor0011).

Answer (score 0):

I made the simple code for your problem. It is not good but you can refer with that idea for fix your problem.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var activeField: UITextField?

    @IBOutlet weak var loginFieldsView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mobileNo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!
    var originalHeight:CGFloat!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mobileNo.delegate = self
        textFieldPassword.delegate = self
        originalHeight = self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y

        registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    @IBAction func btnLoginAction(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    deinit {

        //NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        self.deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
    }


    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {

        //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications() {

        //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {

        //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        if self.activeField != nil {
            if self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y == originalHeight {
                self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y -= (keyboardSize?.height)!
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {

        //Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        if originalHeight > self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y {
            self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y += (keyboardSize?.height)!
        }
        self.loginFieldsView.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.activeField = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.activeField = nil

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        activeField?.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: @ kishor0011 i have just edit my answer. Please check it.

Comment: That I tried but not solved my problem. In this view is moving out of the viewController.
Thanks

Comment: Please replace with newest code i posted. I tested and it worked.

Comment: I think now the problem is same as i mentioned in my question

Comment: Check when tap on a textField and the same time when tap on second textField.
Thanks

Comment: I mean when view is up and at the same time we tap on both textFields.

Comment: Sorry I cannot emulate your problem with my solution. I will give up now.

Comment: Once Please check it,
While self.loginFieldsView is up then tap on both textFields.
Thanks

Comment: I tried it but view changed nothing. Did you use my newest code? In my testing device (IP5s) it is no issue found.

Comment: Yes I tested your newest solution.

Comment: Ok Thanks
I will try to get solution.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake. I created my own project and loginFieldsView is my self.view. So  in viewDidLoad 
    `originalHeight = self.view.frame.origin.y`
Need to  change to the 
    `originalHeight = self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y`
I updated my answer code. Cheers.

Comment: OK I will check it, and will let you know.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry but same problem is coming.
When view is up then tap both textFields together.
Still same problem.

Comment: Maybe problem is in 
    `self.loginFieldsView.endEditing(true)`
Could you try to comment out this line?

Comment: Yes I commented self.loginFieldsView.endEditing(true)
but still not solved.

Comment: No way. Hope anyone can help you. I cannot imagine where is the problem T_T.

Comment: Ok Thanks.
I will try

Answer (score 0):

Just one change hold your view old frame in a variable and assign it again to your view when keyboard disappear.

```
import UIKit
    class CheckFontIconView: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

var activeField: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var loginFieldsView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mobileNo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!
var previousFrame : CGRect!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    previousFrame=self.loginFieldsView.frame

    mobileNo.delegate = self
    textFieldPassword.delegate = self

    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {

    //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
    if self.activeField != nil {
        self.loginFieldsView.frame.origin.y = previousFrame.origin.y-(keyboardSize?.height)!
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {

    //Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions
    /*var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size*/
    self.loginFieldsView.frame = previousFrame
    //self.loginFieldsView.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeField = textField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeField = nil

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    activeField?.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Ok I will check it, and will let you know.
Thank you

Comment: Please check question 
While self.loginFieldsView is moving up then only tap both textFields.
Problem you will get to know.

Comment: @kishor0011 can you show your view screenshot so that i can get better idea how view move up?

Comment: please remove self.loginFieldsView.endEditing(true) from keyboardWillBeHidden because keyboardWillBeHidden call when editing ends.